# Show inner .NET exception in PowerShell when using WebCmdLet

Tags: c#, exception, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

For a project, we are using the WebCmdLet attribute and a .tt file to generate CmdLets for us.
In order to use those CmdLets, we use Import-Module to load the DLL file when using [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

When something goes wrong in the .NET code it obviously throws an exception, but this is encapsulated in an WebException which is shown in the PowerShell command window. The problem is, it only shows the WebException, not the Exception that caused the throw in the first place.

How can I show the original exception in the PowerShell command window?

I have tried to use `$ErrorRecord` and `$Exception.InnerException`, but this seems to stop working when the stack trace hits the method `ProcessRecord()` of CmdLet.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$Error[0].Exception.InnerException
```

see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx